# Is there built in functionality of finding path of directory exist one step back in hierarchy?

Tags: matlab

I looking for matlab built-in function for finding the path of directory which exist one step back in hierarchy. For example:

```
path = c:\\temp\base\xyz\
```

`path2 = matlabfunction (path)` and returns `c:\\temp\base`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[a,b] = fileparts('C:\temp\base\xyz')
a = 
    C:\temp\base
b = 
    xyz
```

Make sure **not** to include a trailing `\` on `xyz`, i.e. `C:\temp\base\xyz\`, otherwise it will include `xyz` in the returned path.

Comment: If path is "C:\temp\base\xyz\" then is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Yes. Try something like `if strcmp(mypath(end),'\') a=fileparts(mypath(1:end-1)) else a=fileparts(mypath) end`.

Comment: Actually, if you want to make it cross-platform, better check for a trailing `'/'` as well as `'\'`.

Comment: There's also `filesep` which returns the appropriate separator.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
path2 = cd(cd([path '\..']));
```

Comment: Can you explain it more. I am confuse about '\..'

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia Better use [`filesep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filesep.html) for portability

Comment: In this case, even better to use `fullfile(path, '..')`